# Why does requesting a pre-signed URL in the Amazon SDK for a file that doesn't exist return a URL?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I ran into this little bit of weirdness today, and I haven't been able to find anything about it, so I was hoping someone here could help.  I'm trying to get a pre-signed URL for an image in my S3 bucket using the AWS SDK for C# .NET.  I make the request by doing the following:

```
        string url = string.Empty;

        using (s3Client = new AmazonS3Client("aws-access-key",
            "aws-secret-key",
             RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
        {
            GetPreSignedUrlRequest request1 = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest()
            {
                BucketName = BUCKET_NAME,
                Key = "whatever.jpg",
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1)
            };

            try
            {
                url = s3Client.GetPreSignedURL(request1);
            }
            catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception)
            {
            }
        }
```

"Whatever.jpg" doesn't exist in my bucket, but it still returns with a URL.  If I try going to that URL, it just tells me that the specified key does not exist.  This all seems a bit weird to me.  Why does it return a URL at all instead of throwing some exception?

Would it be better to check to see if the file exists first on S3 and then create the request for the pre-signed URL?  Thanks for the all help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Signing URLs is a purely client-side operation (using cryptography).
There is no reason to add a network request to that.

For one thing, this allows you to sign your URLs before uploading them.

Comment: Yep, you're right, I think I was majorly overthinking this.  It just does some formatting and encryption.  It never even hits the S3 servers and just creates a URL.  I'll probably just create something for checking to see if the file exists first then.  Thanks.